# jolt transform - mapping flat to hierarchical (Nested

Tags: jolt

I am trying to map a flat structure to a hierarchical structure using Jolt http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#andrewkcarter2:

My input is a flat structure containing customer details: Below is my JSON Input:

```
[
  {
    "customerId": "100",
    "customerName": "Ken",
    "accountId": "1001",
    "accountType": "SAV",
    "transactionAmount": "100.00",
    "homeaddress": "800 W Trade St",
    "businessaddress": "440 S Church St"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "100",
    "customerName": "Ken",
    "accountId": "1001",
    "accountType": "SAV",
    "transactionAmount": "15.00",
    "homeaddress": "800 W Trade St",
    "businessaddress": "440 S Church St"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "100",
    "customerName": "Ken",
    "accountId": "1002",
    "accountType": "CHK",
    "transactionAmount": "200.00",
    "homeaddress": "900 E 4th St",
    "businessaddress": "500 N Church St"
  },
  {
    "customerId": "100",
    "customerName": "Ken",
    "accountId": "1002",
    "accountType": "CHK",
    "transactionAmount": "116.00",
    "homeaddress": "900 E th St",
    "businessaddress": "500 N Church St"
  }
]
```

Here is my JOLT Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
    "*": {
    "customerId": {
      "*": {
        "@2": "temp.&1[]"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
    "temp": {
    "*": {
      "0": {
        "customerId": "[#3].customerId",
        "customerName": "[#3].customerName",
        "accountId": "[#3].accounts[0].accountId",
        "accountType": "[#3].accounts[0].accountType",
        "transactionAmount": " 
         [#3].accounts[0].transactions[0].transactionAmount",
        "homeaddress": "[#3].addresses[0].homeaddress",
        "businessaddress": "[#3].addresses[0].businessaddres"
      },
      "*": {
        "accountId": "[#3].accounts[&1].accountId",
        "accountType": "[#3].accounts[&1].accountType",
        "transactionAmount": "[#3].accounts[&1].transactions[&1].&",
        "homeaddress": "[#3].addresses[&1].homeaddress",
        "businessaddress": "[#3].addresses[&1].businessaddress"
       }
      }
    }
   }
 }
]
```

The result which i am getting is:

```
[ {
  "customerId" : "100",
  "customerName" : "Ken",
  "accounts" : [ {
      "accountId" : "1001",
      "accountType" : "SAV",
      "transactions" : [ {
      "transactionAmount" : "100.00"
    } ]
  }, {
      "accountId" : "1001",
      "accountType" : "SAV",
      "transactions" : [ null, {
      "transactionAmount" : "15.00"
    } ]
  }, {
      "accountId" : "1002",
      "accountType" : "CHK",
      "transactions" : [ null, null, {
      "transactionAmount" : "200.00"
    } ]
   }, {
      "accountId" : "1002",
      "accountType" : "CHK",
      "transactions" : [ null, null, null, {
      "transactionAmount" : "116.00"
      } ]
  } ],
  "addresses" : [ {
     "homeaddress" : "800 W Trade St",
     "businessaddres" : "440 S Church St"
    }, {
     "homeaddress" : "800 W Trade St",
     "businessaddress" : "440 S Church St"
    }, {
     "homeaddress" : "900 E 4th St",
     "businessaddress" : "500 N Church St"
    }, {
     "homeaddress" : "900 E th St",
     "businessaddress" : "500 N Church St"
  } ]
} ]
```

In the above output, we see that accounts 1001 and 1002 are repeating so many number of times as the transactions. I dont want that to happen and I want the transactions to be grouped under the respective accounts.

So, my desired output should be:

```
[ {
  "customerId" : "100",
  "customerName" : "Ken",
  "accounts" : [ {
    "accountId" : "1001",
    "accountType" : "SAV",
        "transactions" : [ {
              "transactionAmount" : "100.00"
           },
           {
              "transactionAmount" : "15.00"
        } ]
      }, {
    "accountId" : "1002",
    "accountType" : "CHK",
    "transactions" : [ null, null, {
               "transactionAmount" : "200.00"
               },{
              "transactionAmount" : "116.00"
        } ]
      },
     "addresses" : [ {
    "homeaddress" : "800 W Trade St",
    "businessaddres" : "440 S Church St"
  }, {
    "homeaddress" : "900 E th St",
    "businessaddress" : "500 N Church St"
  } ]
} ]
```

Similarly unique addresses only should come in the result.

Is there a way to group the transactions under the respective accounts. Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Answered here https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/issues/575

Note this is complex task.  Pivoting on two different intput values, and then piping that pivoted data into multiple arrays.

It is possible, but messy and probably brittle. I honestly don't recommend it.